.Find to match custom time format value
I am working on a visualiser for my work rota, where it reads the start and end times for everybody scheduled (located in column C of the same worksheet) and creates a visual schedule of a day going horizontally, where one box across is equal to one hour. There are four cells per box.

How I intend this to work:

The program reads the start_time of each person from the input section in column C.

As they are custom times, the values are as fractions (e.g. 11am is 11/24 which equals ~0.458333, 7:30am is 7.5/24 = 0.3125).

I then want to find the corresponding time on the visualiser headings in range N2:CS2, which are also custom times.

I attempted to use .Find, but it is not finding a match in the given range.

I tried different formats of .Find, such as having What:= or omitting it, having the additional parameters or trying with just the default settings, having with Range("N2:CS2") instead of 'Range().Find.

The values of start_time are equal to the values of the visualiser headings.


For row_number = 6 To 100 Step 2
    ' For each of the staff listed on input section,

    If Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & row_number)) Then
        ' If they have a start time on Monday then,

        Dim start_time As String
        start_time = Range("C" & row_number).Value
        ' Make note of their start time,

        Dim rFind As Range
        Set rFind = Range("N2:CS2").Find(start_time, SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        ' And in the visualiser time headers, find the header that matches the start time.

    End If
Next row_number 

I condensed the code as there are elements that I don't think are relevant.

This should work. The most likely explanation is that the "time" values in column C and row 2 are not really the same. If you click on the first item in column C (cell C6, according to your code), what is displayed in (i) the formula bar and (ii) the 'Format' dropdown (in the 'Number' group on the ribbon)? Then, the same questions if you click on the item in row 2 that should match.

Hiya Neil, the formula bar says "07:30:00"  and the format dropdown is on 'custom hh:mm' - this is exactly the same as the visualiser headings (N2:CS2).

With the code suggested by taller, I can find all times after 10am. So I assume the problem is happening because of the 0 in the earlier times. Will figure this out eventually...

I would heavily caution against using any kind of text comparison for these values. If you are storing the values as times (e.g. by entering as fractions) then the values will be stored as numbers by Excel, so you should use numeric comparison only. The .Text property will return the formatted value in the cell, which could easily lead to apparent comparison errors.


Get the searched value with Text property, then using Find with the argument LookIn:=xlValues.

Sub SearchTime()
    Dim rRow As Range, i As Long, vVal, c As Range
    Set rRow = Rows(2)
    For i = 4 To 7
        vVal = Cells(i, 1).Text
        Set c = rRow.Find(vVal, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
        If c Is Nothing Then
            Debug.Print "Not found " & vVal
        Else
            Debug.Print "Found " & vVal & " in cell " & c.Address
        End If
    Next
End Sub

Output:
Found 07:30 in cell $F$2
Found 10:30 in cell $O$2
Found 11:00 in cell $Q$2
Not found 15:00




The column count is consistent for each hour, so you can locate the time (cell) without using the Find method.

eg. Highlight desired cells with green.


Sub LocateTime()
    Const START_COL = 3
    Const COLS_IN_HOUR = 4
    Const START_TIME As Date = #6:00:00 AM#
    Dim aTime, vT, aTxt, iCnt As Long
    aTime = Array(#7:15:00 AM#, #8:45:00 AM#, #9:00:00 AM#, #10:30:00 AM#)
    For Each vT In aTime
        aTxt = Split(Format(vT - START_TIME, "hh:mm"), ":")
        iCnt = aTxt(0) * COLS_IN_HOUR + aTxt(1) / 15
        Cells(3, START_COL).Offset(, iCnt).Interior.Color = vbGreen
    Next
End Sub



Hiya taller, I want to eventually make the visualiser headings adapt to the earliest and latest shift times, so the headings will eventually update automatically so I can't really use constants to set it up :( thank you though!!

I've implemented the code for using Text, and that has been half successful. It was able to find 11am, 5pm, 2pm, 3:30pm, and 1pm, however it hasn't been able to find 7:30am or 8am. Again, I have no idea why! I can't find any obvious answers as to what's making those times different, but I will keep working with it. Thank you for your assistance!

The first snippet could locate 07:30 ( showed in the first screenshot ).

so the headings will eventually update automatically so I can't really use constants to set it up  - No, START_TIME could be loaded from the cell. The 2nd snippet is more reliable.

The issue was to do with the custom time format. For some reason hh:mm would work fine for times after 10am, but not for times with a leading 0. Changing the format to h:mm has solved the issue (and whilst I'm sure there's a more direct way to do it than I have, this works so it's good enough for me).
For row_number = 6 To 100 Step 2
' For each of the staff listed on input section,

If Not IsEmpty(Range("C" & row_number)) Then
    ' If they have a start time on Monday then,

    time_to_find = Cells(row_number, 3).Text
    time_to_find = Format(time_to_find, "h:mm")
    ' Make note of their start time,

    Dim rFind As Range
    Set rFind = Range("N2:CS2").Find(time_to_find, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    ' And in the visualiser time headers, find the header that matches the start time.

End If
Next row_number

Thank you to everyone that assisted <3
